# Disabling KWin compositor from command-line

Tags: command-line, desktop-environment, kde5, kwin

Is there any way to disable KWin compositing effects from command-line? AFAIK it's possible to disable it via **System settings->Hardware->Display and Monitor->Compositor** but it requires a KWin restart.If I'm able to disable the compositor from command line , then I can easily assign a shortcut to it.

Any idea?

BTW I use KDE Plasma 5.19.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To disable compositing:

```
qdbus org.kde.KWin /Compositor suspend
```

To enable compositing

```
qdbus org.kde.KWin /Compositor resume
```

Comment: I get `Service 'org.kde.KWin' does not exist.`.

Comment: @Zamicol The answer worked two years ago, I don't follow KDE development, so I can't say what works nowadays. I'll check if it's changed.

Comment: I've checked the latest preview build of KDE, i.e. KDE Plasma 5.25.90, KDE Frameworks 5.98.0 and **it works just fine**: https://imgur.com/a/XhZjH2t

Comment: Still works fine in 2022 on Plasma 5.26.4

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> is the droid you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When I turned on compositing, it broke the setting window so I couldn't turn it back off again.

I logged in using gnome/mate, opened `plasma-open-settings` and was able to disable it again.